# IE8 CSS Bug? Not displaying DIV correctly with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, upload, internet-explorer-8, yui

This video explains the problem best: http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cQ1Oc9f1L

Basically the directory is located here: http://www.ipalaces.org/uploaderprogress/grrrrrr.html

Is the problem piece using YUI.js as the uploading script. The YUI updates the table's row with new information on every event. So I have it update it with some CSS/HTML so that it does a progress loading bar. It works fine for all browsers but IE. I am not sure if this is a known rendering bug or what, and if there is even a fix for it?

the working-demo.html basically shows that if you just resize the div using javascript, IE renders it fine. Its just updated the table's row with new div information seems to cause rendering issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the bug because you applied that fix. But I did take a look at the source. The way you are animating that progress bar just begs for bugs. Try compatibility mode in IE8 and you will see that it's shrinking instead of growing (because the element is centred) and that progressbar-completed element is 2x bigger then container. Same in Chrome and probably Safari.

This is how I would do it:

[image: progressbar]
<sub>(source: [maikumori.com](http://www.maikumori.com/host/progress.png))</sub>

Make A constant for example 250px. Then you have to make a background image with same size as A containing progress bar as if it was at 100%.

Then:

[background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp) = B = -1 * Math.Round(A * UploadedSize / FileSize)

Pros:

- Takes less markup
- If you make background image 2*A and B = B + A then you can have custom image for "blank" space therefore you can make fancier progress bars easily
- Should work in most modern and not so modern browsers
- Doesn't make a mess if user has css/javascript disabled

Cons:

- A must be constant
- Haven't tested =(

P.S.
Sorry for blinding colours, couldn't change them afterwards ... mspaint

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

If I include this in the HTML then it will work fine:

```
<div class='progressbar-completed' style='visibility: hidden;'></div>
```

It seems like IE is having trouble maintaining the "memory" of the background file when its dynamically created in javascript.

Putting the DIV in the html itself seems to make the memory of the background file persistent in IE.

Comment: Can anyone else figure out why this is going on and how it can fixed and not just worked around.